# How do I apply localStorage to select options AND classList.add?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

Note: I'm using vanilla JS only.

My select options trigger a `classList.add` like so

CSS:

```
body{font-family:arial}
body.uppercase {text-transform:uppercase}
body.comicsans {font-family:comic sans ms}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="option" id="test" name="test" onchange="selectFonts(this)">
<option value="arial">Arial</option>
<option value="uppercase">Uppercase</option>
<option value="comicsans">Comic sans (dyslexic friendly)</option>
```

Script (#1):

```
function selectFonts(element) {
const a = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

if(a == "arial") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("uppercase","comicsans"); el.classList.add('arial');});
}

if(a == "uppercase") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("comicsans","arial");el.classList.add("uppercase"); });
}

if(a == "comicsans") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("uppercase","arial");el.classList.add('comicsans'); }); 
}

}
```

All works fine. Now I've been trying to add `localStorage` so the options and added class remain on refresh by adding the following script.

Script (#2)

```
document.getElementById("test").onchange = function() {
localStorage['test'] = document.getElementById("test").value;}

window.onload= function() {
if(localStorage['test'])
document.getElementById("test").value = localStorage['test']; }.
```

Script #2 works, the selected option remains the same on refresh, however it disables Script #1 - the classes are not added.

To clarify, both scripts work when used individually, just not together. #2 cancels out #1.

Is there a way to have them both work together?

[Here's a working jsfiddle with Script #1](https://jsfiddle.net/strawberrytittymilk/nxdt895b/3/) (adding classes)

[and a jsbin of Script #2](https://output.jsbin.com/qubotezani) (localstorage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Change` event is not firing when you are setting the value for `select`. The value in the select is getting updated but the styles are not applies.

Instead of having two functions you can set the selected value to `localstorage` in Script(#1) and split the `selectFonts` function into to one for getting the selected value and another for setting the styles.  Hope below code helps.

```
function selectFonts(element) {
const a = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

setStyles(a);

localStorage['test'] = a;

}


function setStyles(a) {
if(a == "arial") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("uppercase","comicsans"); el.classList.add('arial');});
}

if(a == "uppercase") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("comicsans","arial");el.classList.add("uppercase"); });
}

if(a == "comicsans") {
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body'), function(el) {
el.classList.remove("uppercase","arial");el.classList.add('comicsans'); }); 
}
}

window.onload= function() {
if(localStorage['test'])
document.getElementById("test").value = localStorage['test']; 
setStyles(localStorage['test'])
};
```

Comment: Working great, thank you! I just have one more (hopefully simple) question.  I also have another set of options with a `#test2` and `selectSize(this)`. Is there anyway to add this to your code to perform the same?

Comment: You can add the condition is setStyles function, and call setStyles when selectSIze selection changes.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to get both selectFont and selectSize. to work in localstorage, only one. I've isolated your addition and added both options. Do you mind showing me? [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kuqebeyiso/1/edit?html,js)

Comment: I dont know what's your exact requirement. Still checkout https://codepen.io/mdjunaidalam5/pen/dyYvajb

Comment: Ahhh I see what I was missing. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple. Every HTML element (and its corresponding DOM element) can have only one of each property, including handler properties, like `onchange`.

So your second script essentially overwrites the select element's `onchange`, and your first script stops working.

That's where `.addEventListener()` comes in. That's a method that appends event handlers - without overwriting the others:

```js
//Await the DOM to be loaded - just like window.onload, but triggers faster
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  //Note that it's change, not onchange:
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('change', selectFonts)
})
```

Redesign `selectFonts` to make it work in this case:

```js
//I've simplified you code a bit...
function selectFonts(){
  const element = document.getElementById("test")
  const selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

  //We do the same things for each value - so, let's simplify:

  //Remove all classes
  for(const font of ['arial', 'uppercase', 'comicsans'])
    document.body.classList.remove(font)
  //Add the active class
  document.body.classList.add(selected)
}
```

And your second code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('change', function() {
    const element = document.getElementById("test")
    const selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    window.localStorage.setItem('test', selected)
  })

  const selected = window.localStorage.getItem('test')
  if(selected){
    for(const elem of document.getElementById("test").options){
      if(selected === elem.value){
        elem.selected = true
        break
      }
    }
    document.body.classList.add(selected)
  }
})
```

See it live on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/FZs111/full/RwWpEWy)